# Foreign Key constraint in Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby

Ok first off i have looked at google for hours trying to make my foreign key constraint work and no luck so far.

I will post the variations i have tried (which is basically every one i have seen on google).

This is my create statement which works perfectly, now i try to add a foreign key on Username column.

```
public final String CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Questions(QuestionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,"
        + "SubmittedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"
        + "Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
        + "Text VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,"
        + "Username VARCHAR(10),"
        + "Rating INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)";
```

I have tried adding these next to Username:

```
+ "Username VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT username_fk FOREIGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES Users(Username),"
```

```
+ "Username VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT username_fk REFERENCES Users(Username),"
```

And a couple others which I can't remember now (I had lots of tabs open)

I know it doesn't work since when i add these i get the following when i try SELECT from it

```
Schema 'USERNAME' does not exist
```

Which means it didn't create the table and i was trying to SELECT from a table that doesn't exist.

Please help me by telling what i need to write in order to define a column as a foreign key of another table.

I am trying to set Username of table Questions a foreign key of Username (Primary Key) of table Users.

This is with Derby and Java.

Comment: It seems that you aren't actually certain what SQL you ran, and what it did. Why don't you start over with a fresh database, and use a tool like Derby's "ij" tool or a tool like SquirrelSQL to learn how the DDL should look for creating your tables. Here's the documentation for how foreign key references should be specified: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html

Comment: I'm using an embedded driver database for derby, i have to only use that for my project.

Comment: I can see that you have to adhere to the rules of your homework assignment, but it's hard for me to understand why your teacher would think it a bad thing for you to learn more about SQL and about Derby. Perhaps you could ask your teacher if it would be OK if you performed the Derby tutorials at https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/getstart/ If the goal of your class is to learn about databases, getting some good basic knowledge about SQL seems like something your teacher would approve of.

Answer (score 1):

The Users table needs to be created first, followed by the Questions table.

The foreign key constraint is added at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE Questions
(
    QuestionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    SubmittedTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Text VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(10),
    Rating INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT username_fk FOREIGN KEY (Username) REFERENCES Users(Username)
)
```